# How I print bill from php?

Tags: php, html, mysql

How I can print bill from web application ?.
the web design by HTML,PHP,and MYSQL .

in below , the PHP code print the result in web page , I want to print the result as hard copy .
so what I do ?

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){ 
                echo "<table border='2' style='width:100%'> ";
                echo "<br>";
                echo "<br>";
                echo $row['finame']; 
                echo "<br>";
                echo "<br>";
                echo $row['scname']; 
                echo "<br>";
                echo "<br>";
                echo $row['file_id']; 
                echo "<br>";
                echo "<br>";
                echo $row['na_id']; 
                echo "<br> " ;
                echo "<br> " ;
                echo $row['phone']; 
                echo "<br>";
                echo "<br> " ;
                echo $row['sex']; 
                echo "<br> " ;
                echo "<br> " ; 
                echo $row['placeOfBirth']; 
                echo "<br>";
                echo "<br>";
                echo $row['birthday
```

Comment: `<table border='2' style='width:100%'><br>` !? please, read [HTML Tables](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp)

Comment: You should investigate the construction of a table => `<table><tr><td></td></tr></table>`

Comment: your question is not very specific and the code looks like a partial copy-paste from some simple manual found on the web. Maybe you could rephrase it with a certain problem description?

Comment: to print the result in table

Answer (score 3):

### See the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/33xhLws7/)

Use `window.print();` in javascript to print the complete webpage

Read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/print)

Answer (score 2):

Print only the elements with the `print` class

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
@media print{
    *{display:none;}
    .print{display:block;}
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div>This is not printed</div>
<?php
while( $row = mysql_fetch_array($result) ){ 
    echo "<table class='print' border='2' style='width:100%'> ";
    // your code....
    echo "<table>";
}
?>
<a href="javascript:window.print()">Click to print</a>
</body>
</html>
```

side note:

1. `mysql_`* is deprecated, use `mysqli_*` or `pdo`
2. your html table is wrong, use `<table><tr><td></td></tr></table>` structure

Answer (score 1):

You can't output directly to the printer. Instead you should call a javascript function that opens a printer dialog and sends the html page to the printer. Add the following code to your page and you should be good to go.

```
<a href="javascript:window.print()">Click to Print This Page</a>
```

You can also add the javascript code to the onload method in the body tag so the dialog shows up when the page loads.